# Flutter, How to Clip a Container Like an Arc

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a container i need to clip it's height and that will look like the image provided.i have tried customPaint widget also but can not able to get it working.

[image]

```
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 12,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
            color: ColorConstants.redColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
      ),
    ),
```

```
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with `CustomClipper`

Try this [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/dbb28beac2045b39876a734fc663c383)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: ArcClipper(),
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArcClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .03, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .2, size.height * .5, size.width * .03, 0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [clippy_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter), it provides varies type of clips default.